# Capture video/audio from webcam, view it and send as a file to server (ex. youtube) in flash/actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, video, webcam

I'm new in AS and trying create util such Youtube's "My webcam".
Here's a part of my code:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera(cameraIndex.toString());
VideoDisplay.attachCamera(camera); //view yourself
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(0);

video = new Video();
netconnection = new NetConnection;
netconnection.connect(null);

netstream = new NetStream(netconnection);
netstream.attachAudio(mic);
netstream.attachCamera(camera);

video.attachNetStream(netstream); //store video
```

Can't attach video object or stream to spark.components.VideoPlayer to view video and don't know how to convert video to flv contents for sending in POST form.

Any thoughts?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I retrieved this from the O'Relly Learning AS3 book.

```
1.  var vidConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
2.  vidConnection.connect(null); 

4.  var vidStream:NetStream = new NetStream(vidConnection); 

6.  var vid:Video = new Video(); 
7.  addChild(vid); 
8.  vid.attachNetStream(vidStream); 

10. vidStream.play("video_name.flv");
```